# Google Test for OpenCv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, googletest

I am trying to write gtest for an openCV function that reads in a VideoCapture object and returns it FPS rate as a double value.

```
#pragma once
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

This is my Header file for the Class Calculate FPS that has the function getFps()

/* Class create to calculate the 
fps value of the video object give*/

class CalculateFps
{
public:

    /* return the fps value as
    of type double for the video */
    double getFps(VideoCapture cap);
};
```

This is my .cpp file that implements the header file

```
#include "CalculateFps.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


double CalculateFps::getFps(VideoCapture cap)
{

    /* Returns the fps value of the video
    as of type double */

    return cap.get(CAP_PROP_FPS);
}
```

Can someone help me how I should go about writing a gtest for this function, given that the function can take in any video as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

Which direction do you want to go with the tests? Do you want to check if correct FPS is returned for different streams (1), or proper method is used to obtain FPS (2), or use `CalculateFps` in other classes (3)?

If 1st case - I don't see much value added to this particular function. It is safe to assume that openCV correctly returns proper FPS value for different `VideoCapture` objects. I'm sure openCV has tests for different kinds of video capture. If you insist on testing your implementation, I assume you need to create a test video file of some known FPS, open it in test and feed to your method:

```
TEST(CalculateFpsTest, ReadFpsFromVideo) {
    // I'm not familiar with openCV, but I imagine sth like that:
    VideoCapture test_video{"path/to/your/15_fps_video"};

    CalculateFps fps_provider{};

    ASSERT_NEAR(fps_provider.getFps(test_video), 15.0, 0.1);
}
```

If the 2nd option: one could mock `VideoCapture` class and in the test check that `get(CAP_PROP_FPS)` is used to return proper FPS. Seems like this method is virtual and class has virtual dtor so it is possible.

If the 3rd option, you can introduce `CalculateFpsInterface` class that is pure abstract and mock it in other tests (I recommend this approach).

This way you don't have to *care* how the fps is really calculated - at some point you don't even have to use openCV for that. The usage the mock will allow you to easily separate the implementation of this method from the interface= (decouple your code from openCV).